# For each dataframe row, add x rows where x is obtained from that row

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got a `data.frame` to which I need to add rows, but the number of rows to add (and their content) is determined from the existing rows of the `data.frame`. I'd also like to end up with a column enumerating the rows of each duplicated group. Here is example data:

```
> A <- data.frame(veh = c("MINIVAN","HEAVY TRUCK"),age = c(2.5,3.5),rows_to_add = c(2,3))
> A
          veh age rows_to_add
1     MINIVAN 2.5           2
2 HEAVY TRUCK 3.5           3
```

and the desired output:

```
> B <- rbind(do.call("rbind",replicate(n=unique(A[1,"rows_to_add"])+1,A[1,],simplify = FALSE)),
+ do.call("rbind",replicate(n=unique(A[2,"rows_to_add"])+1,A[2,],simplify = FALSE)))
> B <- cbind(B,enum = c(0:2,0:3))
> B
           veh age rows_to_add enum
1      MINIVAN 2.5           2    0
2      MINIVAN 2.5           2    1
3      MINIVAN 2.5           2    2
24 HEAVY TRUCK 3.5           3    0
21 HEAVY TRUCK 3.5           3    1
22 HEAVY TRUCK 3.5           3    2
23 HEAVY TRUCK 3.5           3    3
```

Obviously the code I've used here to generate the output is messy, non-scalable, and possibly inefficient. I'm looking for a general solution that would allow me to do this with a larger `data.frame` with reasonable speed, and avoiding loops (attempting to speed up loop laden code is part of the impetus for this question).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31175216/r-insert-multiple-rows-variable-number-in-data-frame) deals with a weaker version of the problem wherein the number or rows to add is does not vary with the rows of the data itself, and the rows to insert can contain `NA`s, but I saw no way to generalize the answer there.

How can I achieve the desired output in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `base R` approach

```
out <- A[rep(seq_len(nrow(A)), A$rows_to_add + 1), ]
out
#            veh age rows_to_add
#1       MINIVAN 2.5           2
#1.1     MINIVAN 2.5           2
#1.2     MINIVAN 2.5           2
#2   HEAVY TRUCK 3.5           3
#2.1 HEAVY TRUCK 3.5           3
#2.2 HEAVY TRUCK 3.5           3
#2.3 HEAVY TRUCK 3.5           3
```

Add the new column the way @thelatemail suggested in the comments

```
out$enum <- sequence(unique(A$rows_to_add) + 1) - 1
#out <- transform(out, enum = ave(age, rows_to_add, FUN = seq_along) - 1) # my slower attempt
#            veh age rows_to_add enum
#1       MINIVAN 2.5           2    0
#1.1     MINIVAN 2.5           2    1
#1.2     MINIVAN 2.5           2    2
#2   HEAVY TRUCK 3.5           3    0
#2.1 HEAVY TRUCK 3.5           3    1
#2.2 HEAVY TRUCK 3.5           3    2
#2.3 HEAVY TRUCK 3.5           3    3
```

---

A potentially faster alternative with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(A)
out <- A[rep(seq_len(dim(A)[1]), A[, rows_to_add] + 1)
         ][, enum := sequence(unique(rows_to_add) + 1) - 1]
out
```

Comment: +1 This works for me, but is quite slow. It takes around 2 seconds to execute on a `data.frame` with only about 550 rows, whose output from this process is less than 34K rows. Any ideas on how to speed this up?

Comment: @Rookatu Have added a `data.table` way. Let me know how it performed.

Comment: I think it's possible `transform` or `ave` is slowing it down - you can avoid both with `out$enum <- sequence(A$rows_to_add + 1) - 1` . A quick test completes the operation on 34K rows in 0.14 seconds for me.

Comment: @thelatemail Using `sequence` is a good idea -  I tend to forget it exists. However, or your code to work after `A` has be expanded, it should be `sequence(unique(A$rows_to_add) + 1) - 1`. Best

Comment: @markus - I was using `out` as a different output dataset instead of overwriting `A`, but yes, if you're overwriting you'll need to approach it slightly differently. `unique` won't work because it will collapse if any rows need to be repeated the same number of times. `out <- A[rep(seq_len(nrow(A)), A$rows_to_add + 1),]; out$enum <- sequence(A$rows_to_add + 1) - 1` for instance.

Comment: The data.table solution is considerably faster for me. A great help, thanks a lot!

Comment: @thelatemail I see now. Makes totally sense. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need `uncount` from `tidyr` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

A %>% 
  uncount(weights = rows_to_add + 1, .id = "enum") %>%
  mutate(
    enum = enum - 1
  )

          veh age rows_to_add enum
1     MINIVAN 2.5           2    0
2     MINIVAN 2.5           2    1
3     MINIVAN 2.5           2    2
4 HEAVY TRUCK 3.5           3    0
5 HEAVY TRUCK 3.5           3    1
6 HEAVY TRUCK 3.5           3    2
7 HEAVY TRUCK 3.5           3    3
```

Comment: When I try to use this solution I get an error because some of my columns are `POSIXlt` which `uncount` doesn't seem to like? I'm not sure that modifying existing columns will be acceptable for what I'm doing. Any other ideas?

Comment: That shouldn't happen. It'd help if you edited your test data set to include that column.